# Can I use a terniary in an html helper?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Curious if it is possible to use a terniary (sp?) in my lambda expression in an html helper.  For example I have a search form that uses the same fields but displays different headings depending on the 2 possible classes of items being searched.

For example, if the type is 'PS' I want to use the heading for property 'BrandNamesPS'.  Otherwise, I want to use the heading for 'BrandNames'.

I tried this:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => {(isPS == false) ? x.BrandNames : x.BrandNamesPS}, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "filterlabels"})
```

But I end up with this error:

"InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions."

I can obviously do a simple if else but I'd like to keep it on the one line if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use a ternary operator to set the `expression` parameter:

```
@Html.LabelFor((Expression<Func<MyModel, string>>)(isPs ? x => x.BrandNamesPS : x => x.BrandNames), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "filterlabels"})
```

Or set a variable and pass that into the `LabelFor` helper:

```
@{
    Expression<Func<MyModel, string>> expression = 
        isPs ? x => x.BrandNamesPS : x => x.BrandNames;
}
@Html.LabelFor(expression, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "filterlabels"})
```